# How do I change the umask of a shared docker volume?

Tags: apache, docker, ftp, shared-hosting, docker-volume

This is related to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477636/how-do-i-implement-a-shared-hosting-like-service-with-docker".

I am trying to setup a bunch of apache-php containers that should be able to `rw` to the docroot, and one single sftp container that should also be able to `rw` to the same directory. So, the plan is to create a shared volume, and mount it inside both containers (obviously in different places when it comes to the sftp container). I modified the official php:7-apache launch script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

### > My stuff
chmod g+s /var/www/html
chown -R :2048 /var/www/html
umask
umask 0002
umask
### < My stuff

# Apache gets grumpy about PID files pre-existing
rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid

exec apache2 -DFOREGROUND
```

and in fact the two `umask` lines confirm that the sandwiched `umask 0002` runs correctly. However, when I `bash` into the container and test this myself, `umask` returns `022`, and if I create any file, they in fact get permissions `644`. I can then manually `umask 0002` and any new file gets created with permissions `664` (and `775` for directories).

For this use case, it is critical that both containers (sftp and apache) can read and write in the shared volume. So, how do I go about this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm currently trying to work through a somewhat similar issue, but not exactly the same. If you've found a solution, it'd be nice if you could post it and share your findings, etc.

Comment: Haven't found one, sorry.

Comment: Or rather, I setup the two containers with matching user:group numbers so they appear to be happy.

Comment: Yeah... that's the only hack that works in Docker world atm... 