# How do I mount --bind inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, bind, mount

I have this container based on `debian:jessie` (but this is not very relevant as I had the same issue with `alpine:3.3`). I get to the point where I need to

```
mount --bind /htdocs/www /home/user/example.com/www
```

and I get

```
mount: permission denied
```

I can't find anything in any kernel log, and `-vvv` yields nothing interesting. I obviously can do this on the host (with any other pair of subtree/node). In my example above /htdocs/www is the mountpoint of a Docker volume, but it doesn't appear like it's of any importance, as I can't `mount --bind` any pair of subtree/node inside the container.

Comment: Is there a reason to mount from inside the container? Running the container with `-v /home/user/example.com/www:/htdocs/www` may be a better solution, as its transparent to the container where those files came from, and it doesn't require giving the container additional privileges

Comment: Good point. However, that forces me to recreate the container every time I want to add a new user and/or another site to an existing user. I want to be able to do this on a running container, without having to interrupt it.

Comment: you shouldn't put multiple sites in a container; spinning up a container takes roughly 300 milliseconds. Having just a single site in a container, makes it a lot cleaner as well; you only have what's needed for -that- site, and (e.g.) you don't need to worry about possibly conflicting (site-a, site-b)

Comment: I never said I was going to put multiple sites in a container. In fact, every subdomain will have its own apache/php container. What I'm doing here is having a single sftp-server container. Unfortunately I can't do hostname-based proxying with ssh/ftp, so this is the way it has to be: one container, multiple users, mount-binds and/or symlinks (depending on the chroot status). I could have said that this question was related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546147/how-do-i-change-the-umask-of-a-shared-docker-volume which in turn was related to another one.

Comment: ah, right, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For using the `mount` system call, you need the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability. By default, Docker drops all capabilities when spawning a container (meaning that even as *root*, you're not allowed to do everything). See the [mount(2) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) for more information.

You can start your container with the `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` flag to add this capability to your container:

```
root@host > docker run --rm -it --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN debian:jessie
root@ee0b1d5fe546:/# mkdir /mnt/test
root@ee0b1d5fe546:/# mount --bind /home /mnt/test/
root@ee0b1d5fe546:/#
```

**Use this with caution**. Do not run untrusted software in a privileged container.

Comment: I promise I'll be very careful :) Thanks.

Comment: I get: `/# mount --bind /home /mnt/test/
mount: /home is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount /home read-only`

Comment: This changed the error from "permission denied" to "failed". Even adding all capabilities still fails. Using privileged=true as per Javier's answer works.

Comment: This used to work for me with --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN - but recently I found that it works only with --privileged

Answer (score 8):

Try with `--privileged` flag:

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged=true debian
mkdir /mnt/test
mount --bind /home /mnt/test/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching some info's for Docker/Kubernetes to give capabilities permission, and found some informations

```
docker run --rm -it --security-opt apparmor:unconfined --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN debian:jessie
mkdir /mnt/test
mount --bind /home /mnt/test/
```

would help.